# What is the purpose of question mark(?) after a variable in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am new to grails I found in many examples that a variable may end with question mark (?) 
like this

```
boolean equals(other) {
    if(other?.is(this))
    return true
}
```

above code contains If condition in that other is ending with a ? so I want to know the meaning of that representation

Comment: The same operator appears in some automatically generated Groovy scripts in Bonita Studio.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`?.` is a null safe operator which is used to avoid unexpected NPE.

```
if ( a?.b ) { .. }
```

is same as

```
if ( a != null && a.b ) { .. }
```

But in this case `is()` is already null safe, so you would not need it

```
other.is( this )
```

should be good.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Groovy, but how does `other.is` work if `other` is null?

Comment: Good Question. The implementation of `is` lies in [DefaultGroovyMethods](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L179) where the caller and callee is represented by param to this method and then checked for object reference equality, so there is no operation done on the caller.

Comment: NPE = `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 16):

There is a subtlety of `?.`, the [Safe navigation operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_safe_navigation_operator), not mentioned in @dmahapatro's answer.

Let me give an example:

```
def T = [test: true]
def F = [test: false]
def N = null

assert T?.test == true
assert F?.test == false
assert N?.test == null // not false!
```

In other words, `a?.b` is the same as `a != null && a.b` only when testing for a boolean value. The difference is that the first one can either evaluate to `a.b` or `null`, while the second one can only be `a.b` or `false`. This matters if the value of the expression is passed on to another expression.

Comment: Isn't null "falsy"?   (See https://innovalog.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JMWE/pages/152568042/Data+types+in+Groovy#DatatypesinGroovy-Booleans )