# Safe Navigation Operator, its working?

Tags: grails, groovy

```
def Abc(){
    return this.abc?.equals(bcd.toString()) 
}
```

Also, trying to convert this to Java.

abc is a String.
I understand that the '?' operator would do a null check and 'abc' it is not null it would go ahead and execute the equals part and return true or false on the basis of it, but what if it finds a null?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of question mark(?) after a variable in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186387/what-is-the-purpose-of-question-mark-after-a-variable-in-groovy)

Comment: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_elvis_operator

Comment: It's not the Elvis operator. It's the [safe navigation operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_safe_navigation_operator).

Comment: Yes, it will return `null` and only `null` (no Groovy Truth here)

Comment: I guess it would return a false, and not a null.
According to the answer from @JJJ

Comment: @JJJ thanks for the answer (y)

Comment: It will return null unless it gets cast to an bool.  But that `def` is basically `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as a short hand for the following:

`return this.abc == null ? null : this.abc.equals(bdc.toString())`

According to the Groovy Language Documentation

> The Safe Navigation operator is used to avoid a `NullPointerException`. Typically when you have a reference to an object you might need to verify that it is not `null` before accessing methods or properties of the object. To avoid this, the safe navigation operator will simply return `null` instead of throwing an exception

So it will return `null` instead of `false`.

Comment: After reading it out, I guess this is the interpretation in java :
( this.abc != null && this.abc.equals(bcd.toString()) )

Comment: Hmm, you're absolutely right !!
But if I change this piece of code into java, I would want the return type of the method to be boolean, in which case, I won't be able to return a null, neither I would want it to throw a null pointer.
Therefore, the java interpretation that would help here, would be the one I posted!

Comment: Yes, if you want to return a boolean then you should use the code that you suggested. However, your original question was regarding what will Groovy return if the Safe Navigation operator returns `null`